# Create a Spark dataframe with thousands of columns and then add a column of ArrayType that hold them all

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'd like to create a dataframe in Spark with Scala code like this:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | .. | col_2048 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.123 | 0.234 | ... | ... | 0.323 |
| 0.345 | 0.456 | ... | ... | 0.534 |

Then add an extra column of ArrayType to it, that holds all these 2048 columns data in one column:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | .. | col_2048 | array_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.123 | 0.234 | ... | ... | 0.323 | [0,123, 0.234, ..., 0.323] |
| 0.345 | 0.456 | ... | ... | 0.534 | [0.345, 0.456, ..., 0.534] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
df.withColumn("array_col",array(df.columns.map(col): _*)).show
```

Answer (score 1):

**PySpark:**

Create column list and use python map.

```
cols = df.columns

df.withColumn('array_col', f.array(*map(lambda c: f.col(c), cols)))
```